# iterate though JSON array in p5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, p5.js

I have a server that returns :
[image: JSON Image]

I want to iterate through this data in p5.js

```
var ms = []

function preload() {
  var url ='https://dest/url'
  ms = loadJSON(url)
}
```

Which I expected to return an array but it does not seem to return anything sensible.

[image: Chrome debug of JSON]

However, if I paste the same data into the Javascript console I get different data :

[image: pasted JSON]

How do I either iterate over this data (it is NOT loaded as an array) or convert it to an array?

Comment: That appears to be an array. An array is just a JS object with numerical keys for indices, and a `length` field, basically.

Comment: it's an array you could prove it with **console.log(ms[0].rate)**

Comment: it is NOT an array I am afraid

ms.length is undefined
yet
ms[0].rate works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
var array;
for (var key in ms) {
   if (!array) {
      array = [a[key]];
   } else {
      array.push(a[key]);
   }
}
console.log(array); // [ {'time': .... }, {...}, .. ]
```

Comment: ms is just OBJECT with key as {0 : {'time': ... }, 1: ... }

Comment: yup - thank you. 
The strangeness of javascript data structures never fails to amaze me,

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array of objects, Here's how you can simply iterate them

```js
var data = [{"time":"12345","rate":"12345.12"},  {"time":"12345","rate":"12345.12"}, {"time":"12345","rate":"12345.12"}, {"time":"12345","rate":"12345.12"}, {"time":"12345","rate":"12345.12"} ];

for(obj of data){
  console.log("time and rate: ", obj.time, obj.rate)
}
```

Comment: Ah - but in your case, you are creating an array. My example does not.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, what you have is essentially an array or an array-like object to be more precise and these can easily be converted to a proper array like so:

```
ms.length = Object.keys(ms).length;
var msArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(ms);
```

Comment: Yes, I may have been a bit quick to post this, for this method to work your object needs to have a length property. I updated the post with with a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

jettpleyn had the only answer that actually worked in P5.

Eventually though - it dawned on me that I could make my life easier by changing the JSON returned from the server to an object containing an array rather than an array directly

```js
{ "data":
[{"time":"85579.54189181328","rate":177.66287},{"time":"81978.61475682259","rate":177.66287},{"time":"78377.54175782204","rate":177.66287},{"time":"74776.58741879463","rate":177.66287},{"time":"71175.57481980324","rate":177.66287},{"time":"67574.59330582619","rate":177.66287},{"time":"63973.427922964096","rate":177.66287},{"time":"60372.39295697212","rate":177.66287},{"time":"56771.37366294861","rate":177.66287},{"time":"53170.276379823685","rate":177.66287},{"time":"49569.180530786514","rate":177.66287},{"time":"45968.02240085602","rate":177.66287},{"time":"42365.825628995895","rate":177.66287},{"time":"38764.64792180061","rate":177.71416},{"time":"35163.241872787476","rate":177.71416},{"time":"31562.00651884079","rate":177.72556},{"time":"27960.898827791214","rate":177.73126},{"time":"24359.687824964523","rate":177.67998},{"time":"20758.03328180313","rate":177.67998},{"time":"17156.808887004852","rate":174.53839},{"time":"13555.605601787567","rate":174.9276},{"time":"9954.546007871628","rate":175.35431},{"time":"6353.40945982933","rate":175.96582},{"time":"2752.3464789390564","rate":175.84541}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looing at an issue in the p5.js github about this problem, more than one person suggest to do `Object.values(ms)` to transform the object into an array.

It has to be done after the preload function.